# Bootstrap .popover() 'show' & 'destroy' not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I use the bootstrap popover in 'manual' mode 'destroy' and 'hide' not working properly.
When I'm using hide and destroy, popover opacity changing to 0 but its not changing display to none, which resulting that the popover container cover the content bellow it.
Otherwise if I use 'toogle' mode it's working properly.

My code:

```
$('[rel="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'auto',
    container: 'body',
    trigger: 'manual'
});

$('body').on('click' , '[rel="popover"]' , function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).popover('toggle');
});

$('body').on('click' , '.popoverClose' , function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var i = $(this);
    $('.inputInfo').filter('[data-info-id="' +i.data('info-id')+ '"]').popover('hide');
});

// new code
$('body').on('click', function(){
    $('[rel="popover"]').popover('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My temporary solution look like this:

I'm using:

```
$('.popover').remove();
```

to remove popovers

and

```
$('body').on('click' , '[rel="popover"]' , function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

    var i = $(this);
    var thisPopover = $('.popoverClose').filter('[data-info-id="' +i.data('info-id')+ '"]').closest('.popover');        
    if( thisPopover.is(':visible') ){
        $('.popover').remove();
    }
    else{
        $(this).popover('show');
    }
});
```

to toggle popovers

Comment: If i implement $(".popover").remove(), then the popover is not coming on clicking the element. It is coming only if i click outside and then click the element. Is there any workaround for this.

Comment: @sms This question was asked 2 years ago, I believe you should ask new question because solution for newer version of Bootstrap may be different.

Answer (score 4):

If you were using a custom build of Bootstrap, the destroy event won't work if you didn't check off "transitions" in the JS section and are testing in a browser that supports transitions. This is because Bootstrap looks at $.support.transition in jQuery. If this value is "truthy", Bootstrap assumes there will be a transitionEnd event of some sort and won't detach the popover until this event is received. But Bootstrap uses custom events defined in their transitions library so the transitionEnd call will never be triggered. If you don't want to re-download the customized library, the transitions code is here: [transition code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/83bfff7f0765503b990b96c303eef67009e48d77/js/transition.js)

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to hide the popover use this instead:

```
$('.inputInfo').filter('[data-info-id="' +i.data('info-id')+ '"]').click();
```

Comment: Yes I'll be working is this case but what when I want to hide all popovers in the website for e.g. when I click body? that will show all hidden popovers and hide all visible...

Comment: Looks like that's what you're wanting to do by using toggle

Comment: Not exactly, I want to use toggle when I'm closing it but when I'm clicking any other website elements I expect to hide all popovers (I added new code upper) and In this case It's not working

Comment: Did you try changing the .popover('hide') to .click() in your new code?

Comment: Yes I try to add `$('body').on('click', function(){
  $('[rel="popover"]').click();
 });` and the effect is that, the visible popovers are hiding and hidden are showing.

Answer (score 1):

Work's for bootstrap  popover

```
<span class="pop-target">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="popover"........> </a>
    </span>



  $(".pop-target a").popover('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding this in css file:

```
.popover.fade{z-index:-1;}

.popover.in{z-index: inherit}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Works for hover events:

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('.popover').remove();
 });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.